# density of the product of uniformly distributed random variables

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be  independent with uniform distribution over $(0,a)$ and set $Z=X^2Y^2$. What is the joint density of $Z$
\begin{align}
F_{Z}(t) &= \mathbb P(X^2Y^2<t)
= \begin{cases}
0,& t<0\\
1,& t>a^4
\end{cases}
\end{align}
Consider the case when $0<t<a^4$
$$F_{Z}(t) = \mathbb P(XY<\sqrt t)=\int\int_{xy<\sqrt t}f(x,y)dxdy=\int\int_{xy<\sqrt t}f_X(x)f_{Y}(y)dxdy =1/a^2 \int_{\sqrt t/a}^{a}dx\int_{\sqrt t/x}^{a}dy$$
Are the integration limits set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You should integrate below the hyperbola $yx=\sqrt{t}$ or $y=\frac{\sqrt{t}}{a}$ at the picture:

[image]

So 
$$
F_{Z}(t) = \mathbb P(XY<\sqrt t)=1/a^2 \int_0^{\sqrt t/a}dx\int_0^a dy + 1/a^2  \int_{\sqrt t/a}^a dx\int_0^{\sqrt t/x} dy 
$$

Here is slightly modified picture with integration bounds for $y$ are drawn at each $x$.

[image]

Comment: So if $x$ from $0$ to $\sqrt t/a$ then $a$ y is higher then and i have to y from $0$ to $a$ but why when $x$ equals $\sqrt t/a$ $y$ equals $0$? $x = \sqrt t/a$ then $y = a$ I mean the integration limits in the second integral are from $a$ to $\sqrt t/x$

Comment: If $x=\sqrt{t}/a$ then any value of $0<y<a$ satisfy inequality $xy\leq \sqrt{t}$. Indeed, 
$$0<y<a \quad \text{then}\quad 0\cdot x < yx< ax=\sqrt{t} .$$
Do you see that $yx\leq \sqrt{t}$ $\iff$ $y\leq \frac{\sqrt{t}}{x}$ is the region below the hyperbola? To integrate over this region is to integrate separately: if $0<x<\sqrt{t}/a$ - left from dotted line, then any $0<y<a$  siuts us. For any $x$ right from dotted line, $y$ can vary from the bottom of the square (from $0$) to the hyperbola, i.e. to the $y=\sqrt{t}/x$.

Comment: Thank you very match, I was a little confused, but you really helped me.

Comment: With pleasure. Just in case, I add a picture with integration bounds for $y$. Apologize for the lack of ability to draw.